# Meteor: Multiple submit forms or any event that would let me extract data from my template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, meteor

I'm making a little app in meteor to store car inspection registries, it uses an "autoform" form to insert the values that i need then i present those values somewhere else, one of my templates presents all items stored in the collection and i managed to make a "details" button that shows a modal that should have more details.

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dywcX.png)

[Modal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrbDE.png)

Currently i have a hidden field with the id from the item in the collection, i send that id with a session and the template with the modal gets that session.

```
<form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-warning" ><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Detalles</button> //submit button
  <input type="hidden" name="idp" value={{_id}} size="1"> //Hidden field with item id
</form>
```

It's working just fine, **the problem is that i need the other buttons in the panel to act differently, yet all of them need the id from the item in the collection**. The only way i know how to catch the contents from an element in a template is through **event.target."elementName".value** and this only works with the **submit** event i think, i tried **document.getElementById** with the **click** event but that only showed the first item in the collection, even if i clicked on the "details" button of another item.

The event code:

```
Template.Inspeccion.events({
  'submit form'(events){
      event.preventDefault();
      var id= event.target.idp.value;
      Session.set('id-carro', id);
      Modal.show('Detalles');
  },
```

The modal code:

```
Template.Detalles.helpers({
  carro: ()=> {
    var id= Session.get('id-carro');
      return Inspeccion.findOne({_id:id});
 },
});
```

Is there anyway to listen to different submit buttons or is there any other way to extract the contents from the template and use a different event that will work per button?

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something obvious but i can't find a solution online.

Thanks in advance and Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define click events on buttons and refer to the current data context with `this` in your javascript. Ex:

html:

```
<button id="foo">click me</button>
```

js:

```
Template.Inspeccion.events({
  'click #foo'(){
    console.log(this._id); // "this" will be the data context that was clicked on
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked! never tried "this" for some reason

Comment: Great! Please go ahead and accept the answer if it worked for you.